# Is the relative acceleration with respect to a translating frame equal to that with respect to a fixed one?

Tags: dynamics

[image: A rigid body with a translating (not rotating) reference frame, x'y'z', attached at point A, relative to the fixed frame, xyz, at O.]

My book, written by Beer, states that the rate of change of a vector is the same with respect to a fixed frame and with respect to a frame in translation.
But while it says the derivative **˙**rB/A represents the rate of change of rB/A with respect to the frame Ax′y′z′, *as well as* with respect to the fixed frame, it says the derivative **˙**vB/A defines  the acceleration aB/A of B relative to the frame Ax′y′z′.(aB/A of B relative to the frame Oxy isn't mentioned on the same page of the book.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that in all likelyhood, I am repeating the book text.

If the coordinate system A ($Ax'y'z'$) translates parallel with a constant velocity and acceleration from the fixed system O($Oxyz$), then the following equations hold:

$$r_{A|O} + r_{B|A} = r_{B|O}$$

where:

- $r_{A|O}$ is the position of A with respect to O (usually this is abbreviated to $r_{A}$ because O -the fixed system-  is implied)
- $r_{B|O}$ is the position of B with respect to O
- $r_{B|A}$ is the position of B with respect to moving frame A

When you differentiate that over time

$$\dot{r}_{A|O} + \dot{r}_{B|A} = \dot{r}_{B|O}\rightarrow v_{A|O} + v_{B|A} = v_{B|O}$$

i.e. **the velocity of point B with respect to the fixed system O is equal to the vector addition of the the velocity of point A with respect to the fixed system O AND the velocity of point B with respect to the fixed system A**

Respectively (by differentiating again over time):

$$\ddot{r}_{A|O} + \ddot{r}_{B|A} = \ddot{r}_{B|O}\rightarrow $$
$$a_{A|O} + a_{B|A} = a_{B|O}$$

i.e. **the acceleration of point B with respect to the fixed system O is equal to the vector addition of the the acceleration of point A with respect to the fixed system O AND the acceleration of point B with respect to the fixed system A**

### example

[image]

Assume this man walking  in the wagon of a train which is moving with 6[m/s]. His velocity relative to the train is 1[m/s].

Then:

- $v_{A|O}=  6[m/s]$  the relative velocity of the train with the fixed observer
- $v_{B|A}= 1[m/s]$ is the relative speed of the man wrt to the train

then the velocity of the man wrt to the fixed observer is

- $v_{B|O}= v_{A|O} + v_{B|A}= 6+1=7 [m/s]$ is the velocity of the man wrt to the ground.